# HTTP 400 error: formatting properly a JSON request using React

Tags: reactjs, json, post

I'm working on a POST request from React to Ruby on Rails backend; I tested the endpoint using Postman with the bellow data in JSON format:

```
{
    "amount": 2,
    "name": "Cheese and Loroco",
    "price": "1.55"
}
```

And it worked(status 200); now, from React my JSON request looks like this:

```
{"ordertemp":[{"name":"Cheese and Loroco","amount":1,"price":"1.25"}]}
```

And I'm obtaining a status 400.

So the code that I'm using to generate the request is the bellow:

```
await fetch("http://localhost:3000/ordertemps", {
  method: 'POST',
  BODY: JSON.stringify({
    //user: userData,
    ordertemp: cartCtx.items,
  }),
});
```

About my backend, I'm obtaining this otuput:

[image: backendoutput]

My controller sourcecode looks like this:

```
class OrdertempsController < ApplicationController
    #GET /ordertemps
    def index
        @ordertemps = Ordertemp.all
        render json: @ordertemps
    end

    #GET /ordertemp/:id
    def show
        @ordertemp = Ordertemp.find(params[:id])
        render json: @ordertemp
    end

    #POST /ordertemps
    def create
        @ordertemp = Ordertemp.new(ordertemp_params)
        if @ordertemp.save
            render json: @ordertemp
        else
            render error: { error: 'Unable to create an order'}, status: 400
        end
    end

    #PUT /ordertemps/:id
    def update
        @ordertemp = Ordertemp.find(params[:id])
        if @ordertemp
            @ordertemp.update(ordertemp_params)
            render json: { message: 'Order successfully updated.'}, status: 200
        else
            render json: { error: 'Unable to update the order.', status: 400}
        end
    end


    #DELETE /ordertemps/:id
    def destroy
        @ordertemp = Ordertemp.find(params[:id])
        if @ordertemp
            @ordertemp.destroy
            render json: { message: 'Order successfully deleted.'}, status: 200
        else
            render json: { error: 'Unable to delete Order.'}, status: 400
        end
    end

    private

    def ordertemp_params
        #params.require(:ordertemp).permit( :clientName, :clientId, :amount, :mealid, :name, :price)
        params.require(:ordertemp).permit(:amount, :name, :price)
    end

end
```

So, I would like to request your help with the next questions:

1. should I get rid off the "ordertemp" at the beginning of my JSON from React? in the case yes, how can I accomplish it?
2. what else am I forgetting to get a status 200 instead of 400?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't do ruby, but with postman you are sending this

```
{
    "amount": 2,
    "name": "Cheese and Loroco",
    "price": "1.55"
}
```

whereas on react you are sending this:

```
{"ordertemp":[{"name":"Cheese and Loroco","amount":1,"price":"1.25"}]}
```

They are not the same, so start with the same use case and see if it works.
Also, BODY should be body and you could add headers like in the fetch [example](https://javascript.info/fetch#post-requests)

I noticed in your controler that Ordertemp is the a capitalized letter (I don't know if it matters)